# Autocomplete div under textfield

Tags: css

In my site I have a text field that has to function as a autocomplete box. I use this code within the "headerbar" of my page:

```
Find :<input type="text" class="input2" style="margin-bottom:0px;"  id="customersearchfield">
<div id="customersearchresult" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:999; background:#fff; color:black;   ">
```

CSS:

```
.input2{
    display:            inline;
    margin-top:         4px;
    padding:            3px;
    border:             0px;
    width:              200px;
}
```

This does not work as expected. The resultdiv is placed directly under the textfield vertically, but not aligned horizontally. It just aligns to the left side of the browser window.

How to get the top left corner of the resultdiv directly under the bottom left corner of the text field so that it appears directly under the textfield?

Comment: You mean [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/S4t5G/), or [like this, where there is no space between div and input](http://jsfiddle.net/S4t5G/1/)?

Comment: Hi Vucko, maybe I posted not enough code. The problem that the is an image or text in from of the textfield, so the text field is not at the left side of the screen.

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of the exact situation?

Comment: could you pls elaborate or show some examples what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/XTs86/, it does not align anymore

Comment: @Mbrouwer88 If there is always only the word "Find:" then [this will suit you](http://jsfiddle.net/XTs86/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already using absolute positioning. You're already, I assume, using Javascript to show and populate the `customersearchresult`

Why not position the dropdown at the same time?

```
var inp = document.getElementById('customersearchfield');
var drop = document.getElementById('customersearchresult');

var rect = inp.getBoundingClientRect();

drop.style.left = rect.left + "px";
drop.style.top = (rect.bottom + 2) + "px";
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/Cvoix